# user_access error message

Tags: users

When I log out of my site, I'm getting these notices.

```
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in user_access() (line 798 of /demo/startint/modules/user/user.module).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in user_access() (line 810 of /demo/startint/modules/user/user.module).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in user_access() (line 811 of /demo/startint/modules/user/user.module).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in user_access() (line 817 of /demo/startint/modules/user/user.module).
Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in user_access() (line 820 of /demo/startint/modules/user/user.module).
```

Just as if `$account` and/or `$user` variable(s) failed to set at the beginning of `user_access()`. Drupal 7.19. Does this ring a bell to anyone?

Comment: `$account` could also be `NULL`, but the problem there is that the global `$user` is not a user object. Can you see which function is calling `user_access()`?

Comment: I have just found this http://drupal.org/node/1780004 and will see if Admin Views/VBO is not a problem.

Comment: Check also there is a row in the users table for the uid equal to 0.

Comment: Oh well, I knew I should try to first isolate my own modules. I used bad access argument for one of the menu items. That's it. It'd be great if the permissions page `admin/people/permissions` could list their true phrases ready to paste into a module.